# Triple boot: Ubuntu 14.04 , 16.04 and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

Is there any problem with it? I already have Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10.

EDITED: It worked! The installation was equal to a normal dual boot.

Comment: I have done dual boot with 12.04 and 14.04. I found it to work better if each of them have their own GRUB install. It is possible to boot GRUB from GRUB, which is how I would choose between them. Having both on the same partition was not supported out of the box, but adding a small script to `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks` fixed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There shouldn't be. You will have to create a new partition on your hard drive to select when installing Ubuntu, but aside from that, the installation should be pretty painless.

You can use Gparted to resize an existing partition and to create a new `ext4` one for Ubuntu 14.04.

In the installation, choose the `Something Else...` option when prompted and choose the new partition to install to.

Comment: If it's the Windows partition you want to resize, I'd suggest using Windows tools to defrag, resize, and chkdsk a few times.

Comment: @ubfan1 that is a good point, but it could still mess things up. I always feel safest resizing even NTFS in Ubuntu and then running any checks from Windows.

Comment: It's full working!

Answer (score 5):

You may run into one issue depending on how the drive is set up. A disk with a traditional partition table (Basic MBR (Master Boot Record)) can only have up to four primary partitions. If you have an UEFI (Unified Extensible Firmware Interface) instead of standard BIOS (Basic Input Output System) you probably are using GPT (GUID (Globally Unique Identifier) Partition Table) which is different and the following wont apply.

Each disk can have up to four primary partitions or three primary partitions and an extended partition.

If you want five partitions on a single drive, You’d have to create three primary partitions as well as an extended partition. The extended partition functions like a container that allows you to create logical partitions. So, if you needed five partitions, you’d create three primary partitions, an extended partition and then two logical partitions inside the extended partition.

You could also just create a single primary partition, an extended partition and four logical partitions.

So dealing with three OS's depending on how they are set up and how many partitions were originally installed. You may have to play around with the extended partition of the drive to set it up to allow enough partitions

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is installing right now. If it didn't work, I tell you. I have a ultrabook HP pavillion

Comment: @Vitor well if it has started the install I guess Ubuntu was able to find enough room and had the partition table set properly so it can just add logical partitions. If it didn't have the ability it wouldn't have been able to start installing :D